# How to overcome Syntax error using Sqlite3 UPSERT with executemany in a python multidimensional dictionary with keys as placeholders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, dictionary, kivy

I have json object that I receive from a server, that is converted to a python multidimensional dictionary within a kivy App.  This dictionary I want to insert into or update on conflict a Sqlite3 datatable using `executemany()`.  The problem is I am receiving a `near "ON": syntax error`.  Can someone please give me pointers on how I can resolve this issue? 
I have tried removing the the colon from the query `VALUES` as well as only getting the dictionary.values() with no success.
 
Multidimensional dictionary layout:

```
arr = {0: {'empid': 0, 'empname': 'employee0', 'empnumber': 2000}, 1: {'empid': 1, 'empname': 'employee1', 'empnumber': 2001}, 2: {'empid': 2, 'empname': 'employee2', 'empnumber': 2002}, 3: {'empid': 3, 'empname': 'employee3', 'empnumber': 2003}, 4: {'empid': 4, 'empname': 'employee4', 'empnumber': 2004}, 5: {'empid': 5, 'empname': 'employee5', 'empnumber': 2005}, 6: {'empid': 6, 'empname': 'employee6', 'empnumber': 2006}, 7: {'empid': 7, 'empname': 'employee7', 'empnumber': 2007}, 8: {'empid': 8, 'empname': 'employee8', 'empnumber': 2008}, 9: {'empid': 9, 'empname': 'employee9', 'empnumber': 2009}, 10: {'empid': 10, 'empname': 'employee10', 'empnumber': 2010}}
```

Sqlite datatable:

```
import os
import sqlite3 as sl
    def create_emp_table(self, cur):
        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp_tb(\
                    emp_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
                    emp_names TEXT NOT NULL,\
                    emp_number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)')
```

Sqlite query:

```
    def insert_emp_name_data_mult(self,conn, cur, arr):
        sql_err = (sl.IntegrityError, sl.OperationalError, sl.ProgrammingError, sl.InterfaceError)
        try:
            query = "INSERT INTO emp_tb(emp_id, emp_names, emp_number)\
                        VALUES(:empid,:empname, :empnumber) ON CONFLICT (emp_id) DO UPDATE SET  emp_names=excluded.emp_names, emp_number.excluded.emp_number"
            cur.executemany(query, arr.values())
            conn.commit()
            return True
        except self.sql_err as err:
            print('error', err)
            cur.close()
            return False
```

I would want to insert or update the table using the multidimensional dictionary key:value pair as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Are you using a recent enough version of sqlite? IIRC upsert was added in 3.24, so older versions won't understand the syntax.

Comment: Please show a minimal reproducible example, and the full traceback. Do not post your entire application.

Comment: @Shawn, thanks.  That seems to be my error, I have ```sqlite_version 
3.22.0```

Comment: @Mad Physicist My application is over 1500 lines, so this is minimal.

Comment: Gotta upgrade then, or do something different (Maybe `INSERT OR REPLACE`)

Comment: Post code that reproduces the error minimally, not the minimum portion of the application that does. The idea is to contrive an example that does nothing but create the error. We don't necessarily need/want to know anything about your application. Creating a minimal example will help you solve your issue on your own 90% of the time because removing the irrelevant portions helps you understand the root issues.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I removed the application part and left the function that gives the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) notation you're using was added to Sqlite in version 3.24, and you're using 3.22, which doesn't understand the syntax.

An alternative that works on older releases is to use `INSERT OR REPLACE`. From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html):

> When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation prior to inserting or updating the current row and the command continues executing normally.

So, try using

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO emp_tb(emp_id, emp_names, emp_number)
VALUES(:empid, :empname, :empnumber)
```

However, since your `emp_number` column is `UNIQUE`, this won't act *quite* the same, as the replacement will also trigger if that conflicts, not just if the `emp_id` primary key does. You'll have to decide for yourself if that's a problem or not.

Comment: thank you.  I only removed the ```UPSERT``` query from my example and added your answer query, the rest of the function works as is.  I changed the names and ran your query.  The function updated them.  I changed an employees ```emp_number``` and it also updated that.  So everything works perfectly, thanks again.  I thought about updating my Sqlite3 version on my Ubuntu 18 machine, but I don't want to fiddle with versions that might cause bugs that I have to solve in my current work environment.  Time is against me right now to solve such possible hassles.